# vb.net send email

Tags: vb.net, email

I was wondering how I could send an email from within a vb application? Can any one assist in where to begin?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the [SmtpClient class within the System.Net.Mail namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx)

Example.

```
'create the mail message
Dim mail As New MailMessage()

'set the addresses
mail.From = New MailAddress("xx@xx")
mail.[To].Add("xx@xx")

'set the content
mail.Subject = "This is an email"
mail.Body = "this is a sample body"

'set the server
Dim smtp As New SmtpClient("localhost")

'send the message
Try
    smtp.Send(mail)
    Response.Write("Your Email has been sent sucessfully - Thank You")
Catch exc As Exception
    Response.Write("Send failure: " & exc.ToString())
End Try
```

Comment: The code is going to run on an Microsoft exchange server. Do i need to do something differently?

Comment: Im no expert in setting up exchange servers but I have plenty of applications sending mail through exchange servers like above. You obv. have to change "localhost" with your exchange servers name.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `System.Net.Mail` namespace, look it up and see if it helps. I use C# but I imagine it is similar, create a client, then a message, set params of the message and then `client.Send()` will send the message.