# send an email from a web page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-config

I am trying to send an email from a web page.
 My online web server will only let me use its own email server.

Here is the error code from an internal try..catch:

```
 Insufficient permissions for setting the configuration property 'port'. (E:\kunden\homepages\36\d457818200\www\zSession\web.config line 48)
```

Here is my web.config:

```
web.config
<system.net>
<mailSettings>
  <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="name@email.com">
    <network enableSsl="false" host="smtp.email.com"
    userName="name@email.com"
    password="pass1" port="587" defaultCredentials="false" clientDomain="domainname" />
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

The port is correct at 587 for my web server email.
   It is the SSL setting of my email account.
   I choose SSL to be true because there is an encrypted level on this email server.

The error code exists in the body of the vb code:

```
        Dim message As New MailMessage()
        Dim fromAdd As MailAddress = New MailAddress("name@email.com")
        With message
            .[To].Add("name1@email1.com")
            .Subject = "Choose Session Members"
            .From = fromAdd
            .IsBodyHtml = True
            .Priority = MailPriority.Normal
            .BodyEncoding = Encoding.Default
            .Body = "body"
        End With
        Dim host = Request.Url.Host
        Dim smtpClient As New SmtpClient()
        With smtpClient
            .Host = "smtp.email.com"
            .Port = 587
            .EnableSsl = True
            .UseDefaultCredentials = True
            .Credentials = New NetworkCredential("name@email.com", "pass1")
            .DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network
            .Send(message)
            .Dispose()
        End With
```

Comment: Confused between `I choose SSL to be true` and your web.config `enableSsl="false"`.

Comment: enableSsl should be "True" but my webserver said that it did not matter.  I corrected it, debugged it and it gives the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help.

```
'Name Space
Imports System.Object
Imports System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient
Imports System.Net.Mail



Dim mail As New MailMessage()

'set the addresses

  mail.From = New MailAddress("xx@xx")
  mail.[To].Add("xx@xx")

'set the content

mail.Subject = "This is an email"
mail.Body = "this is a sample body"

'set the server

Dim smtp As New SmtpClient("localhost")

'send the message

 Try
smtp.Send(mail)
Response.Write("Your Email has been sent sucessfully - Thank You")
Catch exc As Exception
Response.Write("Send failure: " & exc.ToString())
End Try
```

Source:-[vb.net send email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862649/vb-net-send-email)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is about it

```
var message = new MailMessage();

message.To.Add("name1@email1.com");
message.From = new MailAddress("name@email.com");
message.Subject = "Choose Session Members";
message.Body = "body";
message.IsBodyHtml = True
message.BodyEncoding = Encoding.Default

var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.email.com", 587);
client.UseDefaultCredentials = False
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("name@email.com", "pass1");
client.EnableSsl = True
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network

client.Send(message);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a conflict between your credentials.

I'd try to change this:

```
        .UseDefaultCredentials = True
        .Credentials = New NetworkCredential("name@email.com", "pass1")
```

To this:

```
        .UseDefaultCredentials = False
        .Credentials = New NetworkCredential("name@email.com", "pass1")
```

[The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.usedefaultcredentials%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says:

*Some SMTP servers require that the client be authenticated before the server sends e-mail on its behalf. Set this property to true when this SmtpClient object should, if requested by the server, authenticate using the default credentials of the currently logged on user. For client applications, this is the desired behavior in most scenarios.
Credentials information can also be specified using the application and machine configuration files. For more information, see  Element (Network Settings).
If the UseDefaultCredentials property is set to false, then the value set in the Credentials property will be used for the credentials when connecting to the server. If the UseDefaultCredentials property is set to false and the Credentials property has not been set, then mail is sent to the server anonymously.*